# How to Config next-images with existing next.config.js file

Tags: node.js, next.js, nextjs-image, next-images

I want to use the npm package next-images in my nextjs app.

After reading the documentation for next-images, it says you need to create a **next.config.js** file with the following code:

```
const withImages = require('next-images')
module.exports = withImages()
```

However I already have a next.config.js file, currently it has code inside it that looks like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');

const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    images: {
        remotePatterns: [
            {
                protocol: "http",
                hostname: "**",
            },
            {
                protocol: "https",
                hostname: "**",
            },
        ],
    },
    env: {
        customSnipcartJS: fs.readFileSync('public/file2.js').toString(),
        snipcartInstallJS: fs.readFileSync('public/file1.js').toString()
    }
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

So my question is, how do I merge the required config code for next-images with my existing configuration I already have in my **next.config.js**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else runs in to something like this I found a solution.

I managed to get this to work, you can pass your custom next config in to the withImages method.

So this now works.

```
var fs = require('fs');
const withImages = require('next-images');

module.exports = withImages({
    reactStrictMode: true,
    images: {
            disableStaticImages: true,
            remotePatterns: [
            {
                protocol: "http",
                hostname: "**",
            },
            {
                protocol: "https",
                hostname: "**",
            },
        ],
    },
    env: {
        customSnipcartJS: fs.readFileSync('public/file2.js').toString(),
        snipcartInstallJS: fs.readFileSync('public/file1.js.js').toString()
    }
})
```